# How to insert a record from a Form with Dialog confirm?

Tags: forms, dialog, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I insert with a Form records in MyTableNewRecord.

In my **insert** Table method iI insered this code:

```
dialog     dialog;
DialogText dialogText ;
DialogButton dialogButton;
DialogField dialogField;

dialog = new Dialog("Dialog user");
dialogText =
dialog.addText("Text dialog.");
dialogText = dialog.addText("Click OK to continue");

dialog.run();
super();
```

For to insert, I use a Form.
In MyForm I used a **SysListPanelRelationTableCallback** for to insert data.
This SysListPanel I created looklike:

```
sysListPanel = SysListPanelRelationTableCallback::newForm(element,
                     element.controlId(formControlStr(SysUserGroupInfo, Users)),
                     "@SYS25440", "@SYS57282", #ImageUser,
                     tablenum(MyTableRecord),
                     fieldnum(MyTableNewRecord, UserId),
                     fieldnum(MyTableNewRecord, AdministratorUse),
                     tablenum(TableFromRecords),
                     fieldnum(TableFromRecords, Id),
                     [fieldnum(TableFromRecords, Id),
                     fieldnum(TableFromRecords, Name)]
                     , 0, '' ,
                     "","");
```

When I put the User from right site to lest site(and add in MyTableNewRecords ), 
the **DialogBox** run, but, when I clicked OK(dialogBox DefaultButton), I give  an error, looklike:

> "Few or too ttsbegin/ttscommit . Current level TTS is 1"

I can insert a records if I only clicked on Escape (X).

How I can insert records after DialogBox?

I tried to insert ttsbegin; ttscommti; maybe I'm wrong to put them, because it gives me the same error.

I have to use another override method, but I tried with validateWritre and not even open the **Dialog** (test in Debug and does not pass through the method).

Or, It's possible to insert a confirm befor to add a record with ListPanel?
I nedd to have a confirm and , after I have to add a record in a Table (MyTableNewRecord).

Thanks for yours time,

enjoy!

Comment: Did you try to insert dialog code before syslistpanel and not in insert method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not write code that allows user interaction(ie a dialog) during a transaction

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609617.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chromableed Studiosfor your time, but I would have the confirmation before continuing. Maybe it's a way a bit difficult for me. 
You're right. The message I get is just an imbalance ttsbegin - ttscommit . My difficulty is in handle

Comment: not sure if you are the downvoter, but this is why you are getting the tts unblanaced. the answer if you must have a dialog is to move it out of the transaction. insert is not a great place for this because among the reasons you already found it also causes set based operations to revert to row by row when you add code to insert.

Comment: Chromableed Studios Absolutely not me,  the downvoter,Now I do the way to say thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the listpanel control, can you override the button press and put it there maybe? Or is there anywhere in standard ax using that control that also throws a dialog?

Comment: maybe try creating a subclass and overriding the methods mentioned at the bottom here: http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2007/10/list-panels-in-dynaics-ax-short.html

Comment: thanks for your time, 
I saw that class, I understood approximately the loop-code. Good advice!
I need to modify some things about the creation of the record.
Thanks a lot, greetings!